# Working with strings, char array, c++ and assembly. Issue passing string to assembly

Tags: c++, string, pointers, assembly

I am working on a C++ and external asm code. It is a requirement for us to work with external ASM libraries. The problem is that, I am having difficulty passing the string from the c++ side to asm. I am sure I am making some mistake in accessing the string on the asm end.

I basically read from a text file, word - by - word. Then I want to pass each word onto the ASM side and process it for some statistics.

Suppose I retrieved a word from the file and it is stored in

```
string wordFromFile = "America";
processWord(wordFromFile, wordFromFile.size()) //processFromWord is the ASM side function

;;ASM SIDE
;;The doubt I have (first of all all) is how do I declare the arguments on the ASM SIDE
ProcessWordUpperCase PROC C, wordFile :BYTE, len :DWORD

OR

ProcessWordUpperCase PROC C, buffer :DWORD, len :DWORD
```

How should I? And one more thing, in the function I am going to access the string by each letter. What do you advise here?

Comment: To clarify - you're using MSVC++ as your C++ compiler, MASM as your assembler? Also, is this x86 or x64 assembly?

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to do anything useful with the `string` *object* in assembler. If anything, you should pass the pointer using `c_str` but then you have to remember it's a *constant* pointer (so you can't modify the string) and the pointer is also temporary.

Comment: MSVC++, MASM, and x86

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a skeleton just counting the length of the string where you could put youir code.

toupper.cpp

```
extern "C"
{
    int ProcessWordUpperCase(const char *wordFile, int arraySize);
};

int main(int argc, char*arg[])
{
    char t[100];
    int res;

    res = ProcessWordUpperCase(t, sizeof(t));

    std::string s = "myvalue";
    res = ProcessWordUpperCase(s.c_str(), s.length());

    return 0;
}
```

toupper.asm

```
.486
.model flat, C
option casemap :none

.code

ProcessWordUpperCase PROC, wordFile:PTR BYTE, arrayLen:DWORD

    LOCAL X:DWORD

    push        ebx  
    push        esi  
    push        edi  

    mov         edi, wordFile
    xor         eax, eax

    dec         edi
    dec         eax

@@StringLoop:
    inc         edi
    inc         eax
    cmp         byte ptr [edi], 0
    jne         @@StringLoop
    ; return length of string

    pop         edi  
    pop         esi  
    pop         ebx  

    ret  

ProcessWordUpperCase ENDP

END
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple trick to get the skeleton of a function is to tell VS to output ASM files.

How to do it:

Crete a new source file with an empty function that has the prototype you want
e.g. `int foo(const char* s, int bar) { return *s + bar; }`

Right click on the a source file and select Properties->C/C++->Output Files->Assembler Output.
Select a value that suits you.
build and look at the generated ASM file.
The generated asm file includes some security checks that can disable by playing with the compilation flags for this file.

Answer (score -1):

From the C side: 
    I'd do it like that: pass the string as an array, alongside with a number of fields in the array. The program will write the pointer to the very beginning of the array to the stack, so if you want to retrieve the very first char in the string, just refer to it as

```
mov eax, [adress of the pointer on stack]
```

Comment: I tried doing this, but I was getting weird characters from the char array. I did:

     char s[64];

 for(int i=0;i<lineFromFile.size();i++){
     s[i] = lineFromFile.at(i);
 }
 int size = strlen(s);
 char *ptr = s;

After this I passed ptr and the size. Gave me error. Any lead?

Comment: For a [tag:c++] `std::string` (as the OP asked for) _`[adress of the pointer on stack]`_ surely won't point to the character data!